# jQuery: Always find next .gallery underneath image in dom-tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

**HTML**

```
<div class="page-content">
    <div class="something">
      <img class="image" src="something alt="something">
    </div>
    <div class="another-div-in-there"></div>
    <div class="gallery">
      //stuff in there
    </div>

    <div class="something">
      <img class="image" src="something alt="something">
    </div>
    <div class="another-div-in-there"></div>
    <div class="another-div-in-there"></div>
    <div class="gallery">
      //stuff in there
    </div>

    <div class="something">
      <img class="image" src="something alt="something">
    </div>
    <div class="another-div-in-there"></div>
    <div class="gallery">
      //stuff in there
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**jQuery**

```
$(".page-content .image").each(function(i) {
    //$(this).closest('.gallery') ??
});
```

How can I find/select the "next" or "following" `.gallery` for each `.image``

So when running through the `each()` loop I want the first gallery for the first image.
When running through the second `.image` I want to find the `.gallery` that is "underneath" the second `.image` in the dom-tree.

Any idea how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin was written for exactly this. *Disclaimer: I wrote it*

http://techfoobar.com/jquery-next-in-dom/

```
$(".page-content .image").each(function() {
    $(this).nextInDOM('.gallery');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

```
$(".page-content .image").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().next(".gallery");
});
```

Here `parent()` goes up to `<div class="something">` and `next(".gallery")` gets next sibling element with `"gallery"` as a class name (if exists).

---

For the updated question you may use `.nextUntil()` method:

```
$(this).parent().nextUntil(".gallery").next();
```

Comment: Thank you, and sorry - I forgot to mention one important thing. See my updated code. There are other elements in there - so it is not exactly the `next()` object.

Comment: @matt Yes, that was important. You may use the updated solution.

Comment: +1... `.nextUntil()` is awesome..! How could I forget that.. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".page-content .image").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().next('.gallery');
});
```

**Edit** : For your updated question:

```
$(".page-content .image").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().nextAll('.gallery:first');
});
```

See a sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uHya7/)